# Implications of convergence in mean square

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider the sequence of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$. Suppose $\{X_n\}_n$ converges in quadratic mean to the random variable $X$. All random variables are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. By definition, 
$$
(*) \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X_n-X)^2=0
$$
This implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X_n)^2=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X)^2$.

Are there implications for the relation between $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X_n)$ and $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X)$? Under which additional assumptions?

Comment: By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\Bbb E_{\Bbb P}|X_n-X|\le\sqrt{\Bbb E_{\Bbb P}(X_n-X)^2}$.

Comment: How do I arrive from there to $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X)$?

Comment: $\Big|\Bbb E_{\Bbb P}(X_n)-\Bbb E_{\Bbb P}(X)\Big|\le \Bbb E_{\Bbb P}|X_n-X|$.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot